# Android add mp3 to mp4 video or convert mp3 to acc or m4a

Tags: android, mp4parser, jcodec, android-mediacodec

I have MP4 (H264) video. created by [jcodec](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec). jcodec not support not encode mp3 audio. i want add mp3 audio to my mp4 video. [MP4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) is good solution for this merge, but not support mp3 format. `FFmpeg` ([javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)) is very large native library and complex and difficult to use.

**so what is easy way to add `mp3` audio to `mp4` video?** *(this question is dublicate BUT awnsers is old and not working)*